# How to work with frame work?

Tags: frameworks, selenium-webdriver

I am beginner in selenium so can any one let me know how can I work with framework or give some example of projects which is made with framework ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Please refer videos from the below link in order to understand the framework,especially videos from 4th session onwards
http://www.youtube.com/channel/UCRTSTOpRhGUN5ETV1Z_gJWQ

You may refer to some of the frameworks from the below github links:

https://github.com/paypal/SeLion

https://github.com/RishiKhanna/MavenWithTestNG

https://github.com/springer-opensource/omelet-example-dataset`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to try out omelet archetype, then a new archetype has been release and you may simply run it as:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.yourGroupId -DartifactId=my-app -DarchetypeArtifactId=omelet-archetype-simple -DarchetypeGroupId=com.springer
```

Then cd into your created folder and run "mvn clean install"

All static files will be created for you